# How can I copy one user account into another? Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7

I have a user account on a Win 7 workstation under the name cperez. CPerez is now gone, and JGarcia is in CPerez' place. We want JGarcia to have her own user account, but it needs to be the same as the old account under cperez. 
Is it possible to copy the contents of the user account into a new user account?
Is there an easy way to do this? It is complicated because the users are in Active Directory in a SBS domain.

Comment: You should be able to do this, using the same software, you use to manage your active domain.

Comment: Thecperez account has drive mappings, data on the desktop and in the documents folders, has email set up, etc. I'm not sure how to replicate this into a new user using the active directory management. Could you explain?

Comment: What you are almost certainly talking about copying is the **Windows Profile**.  There are tools to copy the Windows profile.

Comment: When you created the account for CPerez you probably used a template (e.g. create CPerez from template salesdepartment).  Create JGarcia using the same template. That should give them both the same rights, and access to the same places on the network and the data stored on it. There should be no need to do anything on the local PC.

Answer (score 2):

For the PC itself, use Windows 7's in-built [Windows Easy Trasnfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer).

> Windows Easy Transfer helps you transfer your files, email, pictures, and settings.

It's geared for moving to a "new PC", but it works excellent when the "new PC" is also the "Old PC" with a different user.

I've used it many times to move a user's Local account settings into their new Domain user account (on the same computer).

Beyond that, giving that new user account access to the things the old user may have had access to (drive shares, email accounts etc.) will need to be dealt with from the server-side.

Comment: The old user is a domain user, not a local user, and the new account is also a domain user. Will the Easy Transfer also work in this instance?

Comment: Why don't you just copy all the data in a location both users have permission to?

Comment: @Tokerau Yup, for user files and settings stored on the local PC it will.  Why not just give it a try?  It's not complicated or anything... :)

Answer (score -2):

When you do create the new user profile, consider creating a **generic** user profile e.g. **ClerkL1**, **AccountingAdmin**, etc. Then, when personnel change, no problem!